# How to write this query in laravel? Any Suggestions?

Tags: php, sql, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

**This is the Query which is working fine in MY SQL:**

> SELECT users.name FROM ((event_user INNER JOIN events ON
>   event_user.event_id = events.id) INNER JOIN users ON
>   event_user.user_id = users.id) where events.name like '%FEB%' or
>   users.name like '%FEB%' or users.email like '%FEB%' or users.phone
>   like '%FEB%'

[image]

**This is what I've written which is of course not working:**

```
$data['search_data'] = EventUser::select('users.*')
        ->join
            ('users', 'event_user.user_id', '=', 'users.id')
        ->join
            ('events', 'event_user.event_id', '=', 'events.id')
        ->where
            ('events.name','like', "'$search'")
        ->orWhere
            ("users.id",'like', "'$search'")
        ->orWhere
            ("users.name",'like', "'$search'")
        ->orWhere
            ("users.phone",'like', "'$search'")
        ->orWhere
            ("users.email",'like', "'$search'")
        ->orWhere
            ("users.password",'like', "'$search'")
        ->orWhere
            ("users.work_location",'like', "'$search'")
        ->orWhere
            ("users.profession",'like', "'$search'")
        ->orWhere
            ("users.designation",'like', "'$search'")
        ->orWhere
            ("users.committee",'like', "'$search'")
        ->orWhere
            ("users.role",'like', "'$search'")
        ->orWhere
            ("users.bio",'like', "'$search'")
        ->paginate(10);
```

ok so, with the help from everyone.
I've got solution. Thank you all.

```
     $data['search_data'] = EventUser::select('users.*', 'events.name as e_name')
        ->join('users', 'event_user.user_id', '=', 'users.id')
        ->join('events', 'event_user.event_id', '=', 'events.id')
        ->where('events.name', 'like', '%'.$search.'%')
                ->orWhere('users.id', 'like', '%'.$search.'%')
                ->orWhere('users.name', 'like', '%'.$search.'%')
                ->orWhere('users.phone', 'like', '%'.$search.'%')
                ->orWhere('users.email', 'like', '%'.$search.'%')
                ->orWhere('users.password', 'like', '%'.$search.'%')
                ->orWhere('users.work_location', 'like', '%'.$search.'%')
                ->orWhere('users.profession', 'like', '%'.$search.'%')
                ->orWhere('users.designation', 'like', '%'.$search.'%')
                ->orWhere('users.committee', 'like', '%'.$search.'%')
                ->orWhere('users.role', 'like', '%'.$search.'%')
                ->orWhere('users.bio', 'like', '%'.$search.'%')
            ->distinct()
        ->paginate(10);
```

But this is still returning the repetitive results.

Comment: Do not double-quote your variables. It will add those quotes to the string you're searching.

Comment: What is not working? Do you get an error message or just not your expected output? `like` is not used correctly but in an answer you mentioned that is still not working after pointing to right syntax for `like` so it's not clear what is wrong.

Comment: It is not returning any results. as the SQL query returns results in MY SQL

Answer (score 2):

You need to concat `$search` with `%` like this:

```php
->where('events.name','like', '%'.$search.'%')
```

Comment: It is not returning any results. as the SQL query returns results in MY SQL

Comment: @Ehtasham can u post some of the results that mysql will return.

Comment: @Ehtasham it seems fine. Be sure the EventUser is the table event_user's model. You can use `->toSql()` instead of `->paginate(10)`, and check the raw sql in mysql.

Comment: Thank you @TsaiKoga this helps a lot. but even this one is returning duplicate results.

Comment: @Ehtasham `distinct()` will affect on every columns that you selected, are the duplicated results' columns are all the same?

Answer (score 0):

hmm, thats a long query, I think you can test this:

```
$data['search_data'] = EventUser::select('users.*')
    ->join('users', 'event_user.user_id', '=', 'users.id')
    ->join('events', 'event_user.event_id', '=', 'events.id')
    ->where('events.name', 'like', '%'.$search.'%')
    ->where(function ($query) use ($search) {
        $query->where('title', 'LIKE', '%'.$search.'%')
        ->orWhere('users.id', 'LIKE', '%'.$search.'%')
        ->orWhere('users.name', 'LIKE', '%'.$search.'%')
        ->orWhere('users.phone', 'LIKE', '%'.$search.'%')
        ->orWhere('users.email', 'LIKE', '%'.$search.'%')
        ->orWhere('users.password', 'LIKE', '%'.$search.'%')
        ->orWhere('users.work_location', 'LIKE', '%'.$search.'%')
        ->orWhere('users.profession', 'LIKE', '%'.$search.'%')
        ->orWhere('users.designation', 'LIKE', '%'.$search.'%')
        ->orWhere('users.committee', 'LIKE', '%'.$search.'%')
        ->orWhere('users.role', 'LIKE', '%'.$search.'%')
        ->orWhere('users.bio', 'LIKE', '%'.$search.'%')
   })
   ->paginate(10);
```

Hope it help. Let us know if it worked!

Comment: Still same not returning any results

Comment: hello @Ehtasham, did you changed the variables to suite your project? Instead of ```->paginate(10);```, replace with ```->get();``` and insert the query inside ```dd();``` and check th results.

Comment: Without joins query is working fine. what I get is that the error is in joining.